# Can't use chartr inside function

Tags: r, character-encoding

This is more about the internals of R on how it encodes functions.

I have a function that goes like this:

```
remove_latin <- function (x) {
    chartr("ÁÉÍÓÚÑáéíóúñ", "AEIOUNaeioun", x)}
```

Then I call the function in another function and I get this error:

```
Error in chartr("ÃÃ‰ÃÃ“ÃšÃ‘Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºÃ±", "AEIOUNaeioun", x) : 
  'old' is longer than 'new'
```

So R is encoding the latin characters that I want to remove.
Is there a way to define `remove_latin` so that it doesn't break all the time?

## Edit:

A few months later, more specific information about the error comes to light.

I noticed that having the function in a sourced script brings up the error.
But defining it on its own, doesn't.

Comment: I can't replicate -it works fine for me here. Sounds like an encoding issue though. Can you share any info from `Sys.getlocale()` ?

Comment: Thanks.  I should mention that I'm on Windows too, which probably is part of the cause.  On the locale:

`LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252`

Comment: I noticed something interesting:  if I define the function without the brackets:  
`remove_latin <- function (x) chartr("ÁÉÍÓÚÑáéíóúñ", "AEIOUNaeioun", x)` it doesn't do the error....

Comment: That sounds odd. I can't imagine it would make much difference, but whatever works.

Comment: What a mistery.  I guess I can live with it.

Comment: No error with Linux in a US locale but obviously not with  1252 which is a Windows thing.

Comment: can you present a full reproducible (for you) example? You might actually need to post the sourced file somewhere publicly accessible, as it sounds like an encoding issue and encoding information is often carried along with the file ...